# jQuery anonymous function variables

Tags: jquery, function, variables

I try to accomplish a really simple Task

1. Read data from a service in a jquery loop
2. return the data to another function to plot it into a graph

Here comes the problem were i'm really stuck

```
function readData() {       

    var vname = $(this).attr("name");
    var vid=$(this).attr("id");
    var arrResult = [];

    $("#choices").find("input:checked").each(function () {

        var senddata = {
            databaseURL: DB,
            tracename: variablePath + vname+"\\"+vid,
            startdate: jDateStart1,
            enddate: jDateEnd1
        };

        var jsonUrl = "http://service/trace";

        var jqxhr = $.get(jsonUrl, senddata, function(dataAI) {

            arrResult.push(dataAI.value);
            console.log(arrResult); <<< returns data

        })
    })
    console.log(arrResult); // <<< returns nothing
    return arrResult;   
}
```

The Problem is that arrResult return empty, nothing, null and i really don't know why??
Shouldn't it be that for the anonymous function in the get statement the arrResult acts like a global variable?

Comment: The `$.get` function is an asynchronous function, so it could be executed after you returned the arrResult

Comment: omg, i really missed that part - thank a lot an sorry for the doubleposting!